# Matlab - Image Formation - Matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, reshape, dimension

I am doing a very interesting Computer Vision project which talks about how to "create manually" images with Matlab.

The teacher gave me three matrices: the **illuminant matrix (called E)**, the **camera sensitivity matrix (called R)** and finally, the **surface reflectance matrix (called S)**.
The matrix dimensions are as follows:

**S: 31x512x512 (reflectance samples x *x-dimension* x *y-dimension*)
R: 31x3
E: 31x1**

The teacher gave me also the following relationship:

**P=transpose(C)*R=transpose(S)*diagonal(E)*R**

Where **C is the color matrix**.
Where **P is the sensor response matrix**.

The goal is to display the image formed by all the previous matrices. Therefore, we have to compute the P matrix.

The class of all the matrices is **double**.

This is what I have done:

```
Diag_D=diag(D);% Diagonal matrix of D 

S_reshaped= reshape(S,31,[512*512]);% Reshape the surface reflectance matrix
S_permute=permute(S_reshaped,[2 1]);% The output matrix is a 262144x31 matrix

Color_Signal_D65_buffer=S_permute*Diag_DD;
Color_Signal_D65=reshape(Color_Signal_D65_buffer,[512 512 31]);% This is the final color matrix

Image_D65_buffer= (reshape(Color_Signal_D65,[512*512],31))*R;% Apply the given formula
Image_D65= reshape(Image_D65_buffer,[512 512 3]);% image formation
Image_D65_norm=sqrt(sum(Image_D65.^2,3));% Compute the Image_D65 norm   
Image_D65_Normalized=bsxfun(@rdivide, Image_D65, Image_D65_norm);% Divide each element of the matrix by the norm in order to normalize the matrix

figure
imshow(Image_D65_Normalized)% Display the image
```

However,it did not work at all. The output is an image but the colors are completely wrong (there is too much blue on the image).
I think it could be a matrix reshaping problem but I have tried all the possible combinations but nothing to do.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: of what class is the `Image_D65_Normalized`? (int8, double,...)

Comment: Also, try to use `imshow(Image_D65_Normalized,[])` to show the image. It will scale the color range to be displayed.

Comment: Hi Geovany, thank your very much for your answer. The class of Image_D65_Normalized is double.

Comment: I've tried imshow(Image_D65_Normalized,[]) but it does not work.

Comment: I've finaly found the error. It was a problem in the normalization process. I was using the wronf formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finaly found the error. It was a problem in the normalization process. I was using the wrong formula.